# java 3D render distance

Tags: java, java-3d

I recently started using java 3D for games development. 
I am currently working on an assignment, a simple racing game to be very specific.

What you seeing on this screenshot is just a box, i have given road texture to it, and another box representing a car (which will be replaced by an external model later)

This is another screenshot from a different angle.
As you can see, I am not able to render the whole road, I have been looking to render the whole path from a long time, but somehow, the java3d engine does not want to render the whole road It stops rendering at some point.

What can I do to get over this, I want to render the whole distance, so, the whole road will be visible.

Help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: I don't see a screenshot, or code..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing any screens either, but you're probably looking for `View.setBackClipDistance(double distance)`, which sets the distance at which objects begin disappearing.

Comment: @Tourious, I am sorry mate, but the system did not allow me to upload images becoz of d stupid "reputation" which i dont have.
Anyhow, I am relatively new at java3D, but i am looking up View class, hopefully I'll get what I am looking for. 
Cheers.